# MySql orden clausula ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

Tengo que hacer una serie de selects para obtener información, como siempre hacemos.

La cosa es que sería mucho más fácil  ordenarlas usando primero `ORDER BY` después de `UNION` .

Dejo aquí las consultas

```
select CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR(10)) -- Valor1
from tablaA
where fecha = fechaactiva

Union

select time(llamada) -- Valor2
from TablaB
order by calldate desc
limit 1

Union

SELECT campo -- Valor3
FROM TablaA
limit 1
```

En principio esto no se podría hacer, entiendo que esto está mal y el ORDER BY debería ir al final , o así es como lo aprendí, ¿Como podría hacer para ordenar únicamente los datos de una SELECT?

Este es el error que me da el interprete de **BBDD** que uso.

> **Error de SQL (1221)**: Incorrect usage of `UNION` and `ORDER BY`

Comment: olle y todas las consultas tiene la misma cantidad de columnas?

Comment: Todas las consultas tienen un único resultado , la idea es que después haga un `while(DataReader.Next()` y guardarlos en una lista para automatizar una tarea.

Comment: y has usado union all? o union distinc?

Comment: No conozco esas clausulas, pero de todas formas, me valdría eso para hacer unicamente el order de el select que necesito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piensa que no puedes usar una clausula `ORDER BY` de manera parcial en ningún `SELECT` común, el orden aplica a toda la consulta, aunque en tu caso uses `UNION` el resultado final sigue siendo una única consulta. El `ORDER` siempre es resuelto por el motor al final de todo, cuando ya resolvió el resto de las sentencias, la otra limitación que tienes es que no puedes ordenar por una columna que solo existe en una parte del `UNION`.

También, un dato secundario, que no está de más comentar: es que el motor no garantiza un orden natural cuando no se especifica un `ORDER`, vale decir que sin esta clausula, nunca vamos a tener garantía que las filas tengan el mismo orden siempre.

Para hacer lo que buscas, puedes probar:

#### Usando subconsultas

De esta forma el motor "entiende" que debe procesar primero una subconsulta, que en este caso si puede tener un `ORDER`. Por ejemplo:

```
SELECT  Campo
        FROM (SELECT Campo, calldate  FROM Tabla1 ORDER BY calldate) T
UNION
SELECT Campo FROM Tabla2
UNION
SELECT Campo FROM Tabla3;
```

Sin embargo que funcione o no dependerá del motor, por lo que antes decía, al no tener un orden la consulta final, ¿tenemos garantía que el conjunto de datos del primer `select` va a estar ordenado siempre de la misma forma?

#### Agregando el campo a la consulta

```
SELECT calldate, Campo FROM Tabla1
UNION
SELECT NULL, Campo FROM Tabla2
UNION
SELECT NULL, Campo FROM Tabla3
       ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Esta es la forma adecuada, hay que agregar la columna a ordenar en la primer consulta y retornamos `NULL` en la posición de dicha columna en las otras consultas, de esta forma podemos aplicar el `ORDER` al final y terminamos asegurando que el resultado final tendrá las filas del primer `SELECT` al comienzo y ordenadas por `calldate`. (En un `ORDER` el `NULL` va primero, por eso usamos `DESC`)

Answer (score 1):

Para tu consulta y segun investigue lo podrías hacer de la siguiente manera.
Pero primero algunas aclaraciones respecto al uso de estas.

**UNION:**
Se usa cuando todos los select tiene la misma cantidad de columnas, deben ser del mismo tipo y el mismo orden.

**UNION ALL:**
Selecciona todos lo valores por defecto  y permite valores duplicados.

**UNION DISTINCT:**
Elimina filas duplicadas y solo devuelve filas únicas.

Y la forma que se ocurre de hacer tu consultas sería las siguiente.

```
(select CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR(10)) -- Valor1
from tablaA
where fecha = fechaactiva)
UNION ALL
(select time(llamada) -- Valor2
from TablaB
limit 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT campo -- Valor3
FROM TablaA
limit 1)order by calldate desc;
```

> PD:SI tu versión de mysql es 5.7 para arriba tiene que ser con
>   paréntesis.